# Are Hilbert spaces in Quantum Mechanics time-dependent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, time, mathematics

I'm a mathematician, and am trying to grasp, at least on its surface, the mathematical foundations of quantum mechanics... but there is something that seems just odd with the mathematics.

Suppose i want to model the motion of a classical system through its configuration space $K$ in terms of the real parameter $t\in\mathbb{R}$, where the system makes a path $\lambda\subset K$ between the points $p_i$ and $p_f$ in the configuration space. To correctly model the motion, i can just look for the unique function $\vec{x}\in \Omega_\lambda$ that solves a given set of differential equations:
$$\Phi_k(\vec{x},\frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{x}}{\mathrm{d}t},t)=0$$
Where $\Omega_\lambda$ is the set of all smooth functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow K$ such that
$$\lambda=\left\{f(t)| f(t_i)=p_i\text{ and }f(t_f)=p_f; \quad t_i,t_f\in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$
and $\Phi_k$ depends on whether the formulation is lagrangian, newtonian, hamiltonian, relativistic, etc., So it all comes down to finding $\vec{x}$.

I get that this description is as short as it is vague, but, up to some point, and up to my knowledge, it is very accurate. However, in trying to do the same for QM, a difficulty arises: no function $\vec{x}$ is ever well-defined, as stated by Heisenberg's Principle . I know, by the postuates of QM, that there are roundabouts of this problem that rely on finding solutions to the Schrödinger equation, that can be formulated as an equation
$$\Pi(\Psi,\hat{H})=0$$
where $\Psi$ is the wave function of the system, and $\hat{H}$ its hamiltonian operator... But some questions arise to mind:
First, the wave function is an element in a complex hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, so we need, at the very least, a correspondence between subsets of the flat euclidean space $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^4$ and $\mathcal{H}$, given by
$$\Psi:S\rightarrow \mathcal{H}$$
For these equations to be macroscopically useful or instructive. Moreover, this correspondence must be well-defined... however, i don't see these correspondence even vaguely defined anywhere.
Also, if the wave function can be time-dependant, can't $\mathcal{H}$ be time-dependant too? After all, the wave function is what defines the quantum state of a system, and hence, can also define the basis of the hilbert space. How can the configuration space of a system be time-dependant?

In general, i can't manage to find a consistent way of modeling quantum phenomena that can be made into a consistent pseudo-algorithm, like the one i descibed above for classical physics. Am i misunderstanding something? It can't be a normal perk of QM!

Comment: the Hamiltonian is an operator over hilbert space, not a vector in hilbert space, as the wavefunction is, so I am not sure if your correspondence makes any sense.

Comment: Oh. Ok. I'll edit now.

Comment: This doesn't really make a lot of sense inside the standard framework of quantum mechanics. Have you tried reading one of the many textbooks on quantum mechanics?

Comment: Well... Nevermind. Classic stack Exchange.

Comment: I'll agree with @ACuriousMind, but let me note that there are indeed cases where one considers "time-dependent Hilbert spaces", namely e.g. for the case of a particle in a box with moving walls. See e.g. [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.4252.pdf)

Comment: @TobiasFünke Thanks! I'll check out the info.

Comment: It is not obvious to me why you claim that we need "a correspondence between subsets of the flat euclidean space S⊆R4 and H"?

Comment: *"Classic stack Exchange"* Yes. It is classic stack exchange for someone to post a confused question (with improper punctuation), which could be cleared up by reading a textbook, and then get upset when this is pointed out.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is absolutely no non-mainstream physics in this question. I agree that the question is a bit rambling and uses sightly informal punctuation. If that is a reason for closing questions now, then please use that as the close reason. I also note that practically 100% of questions here could be cleared up by reading a textbook.

Comment: @PatoGalmarini, there is one for the wave function! It is literally defined as a function of space & time. I just can't manage to see an actual equation or expression defining it explicitly: I.e. $\Psi(x,t)$ is the only vector in $H$ such that shroödinger's equations holds true (is this the case?)

Comment: @SimónFlavioIbañez the wave function is not a function to the Hilbert space; it is an element of the Hilbert space (i.e., the Hilbert space is usually a function space). Your description of a classical system applies 100% to quantum mechanics, $\psi$ replaces x and $\mathcal H$ replaces K. I agree that it might be useful to start reading a basic QM textbook from the beginning.

Comment: @Noiralef Yeah the "not mainstream physics" close reason is absolutely silly here. It's the second time it's happened today, and perhaps people are using it as a default close reason for "this question doesn't make sense" or "this question is too trivial to answer" (not that I'm saying those are true for this question).  It might be that the question should be closed (I'm not sure), but certainly not for *that* reason.

Comment: @Noiralef thanks. I'm not unwilling to read a textbook. Just thought that many of the questions here could be easily answerd because they should be common knowledge in the field, but they're not properly addressed on public reservoirs, as Wikipedia. I've never seen, not once, the wave function formally defined for general cases: just concrete examples. If what you commented is accurate, the wave function should be a function mapping time to the hilbert space, and should be unique, otherwise, the analogy breaks apart.

Comment: @SimónFlavioIbañez This is just a bit of a linguistic problem. By "wave function" one would usually mean the state of the system at an instant of time. Thus, the wave function is really just a vector in the Hilbert space, one also calls it the "state vector". The time evolution is then given by a function $\mathbb R \to \mathcal H$. Since the Schroedinger equation is a first-order linear differential equation, the time evolution is uniquely determined by the initial conditions.

Comment: You can define psy as a function of position, or whatever degrees of freedom your system has (which is a particular instance or realization of a vector in H), in which case psy  is a map  from R^3 (if we have a single spinless particle) to C (a complex number), not to H. Psy itself belongs to H. Time is usually not included as a dimension, but as a parameter.

Comment: 1) I think this question should be closed as lacking clarity rather than non-mainstream physics. 2) There are textbooks covering quantum theory for mathematicians.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is not how QM works. The basic axioms is that states are (unit) vectors in a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. The "trajectory" of a system is then a time-dependent vector $\psi(t)$, whose time evolution is given by a self-adjoint operator $H: \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ through the Schrödinger equation

$$H \psi = i \frac{\partial\psi}{\partial t}.$$

There is no concept of a path through space; instead, observable quantities are represented by self-adjoint operators. The possible values for an operator $A$ are its eigenvalues $a_i$, and given a state $\psi$ the probability of observing the value $a_i$ is $P_i = |(\alpha_i, \psi)|^2$, where $\alpha_i$ is the eigenvector corresponding to $a_i$.

In particular, when the system is a particle moving through space, there is a position observable with eigenvectors $\{\alpha_x | x \in \mathbb{R}\}$, and the wavefunction is $\psi(x,t) = (\alpha_x, \psi(t))$; that is, the representation of the state vector in this basis.

Of course, this is by necessity a very brief description. But since your question is "what's the mathematical formalism of quantum mechanics?", a complete answer would just be a QM textbook.

Comment: Thanks. It is actually this brief description what i needed: without interpretations or detailed formalisms. So, if i understood the theory correctly, the configuration space of a quantum system (state space) is not the hilbert space by itself, but the subset of all its unit vectors (wich represent states), and by knowing the eigenvectors of an observable we can predict the probabilities of every measurement related to that observable? Please, confirm if this is correct. I think i have a clearer picture now, so i will be asking better questions in the future. :)

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 2):

Quantum mechanics doesn't describe systems as having a single classical path. Rather, it describes them in terms of states and observables. The state can be described by a vector or operator on a Hilbert space. The state and observables can be used to make predictions about finding a system to have a particular value or range of values of an observable. There are books about Hilbert spaces in quantum mechanics such as "Quantum Mechanics in Hilbert Space" by  Eduard Prugovecki.

If a quantum system interacts with the environment it undergoes a process called decoherence and as a result the expectation values of the position and momentum act approximately like a classical trajectory:

https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.1802

https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189